# - operator with gather using non standard evaluation

Tags: r, tidyverse, nse

I'd like to write a function that takes a quosure as an argument, appends `-` to the quosure, and passes that to `gather`, like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_gather <- function(d, not.columns) {
  dg <- tidyr::gather(d, key = k, value = v, .dots = -!!!not.columns)
  dg
}

de <- my_gather(mtcars, not.columns = quos(mpg, cyl, disp))

> Error in `-`(~mpg, ~cyl, ~disp) : operator needs one or two arguments
```

This is clearly because I need to append each element of the quosure with `-`, rather than appending the entire quosure with `-`. But in my work, it won't be easy to create this quosure in the form of `quos(-mpg, -cyl, -disp)` - so how can I modify `quos(mpg, cyl, disp)` to add the `-`?

I would like to see a result that is identical to `gather(mtcars, key = k, value = v, -mpg, -cyl, -disp)`, the first 3 rows of which are

```
   mpg cyl disp  k   v
1 21.0   6  160 hp 110
2 21.0   6  160 hp 110
3 22.8   4  108 hp  93
```

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973675/error-using-tidyeval-quo-with-gather), but it is unanswered and doesn't seem to deal with the issue of `quos()` rather than `quo()`.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you expect to see as a result of this?

Comment: @42- : see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
my_gather <- function(d, not.columns) {
  tidyr::gather(d, key = k, value = v, .dots =  -c(UQS(not.columns)))
  #or use !!! instead of UQS
  #tidyr::gather(d, key = k, value = v, .dots =  -c(!!!(not.columns)))

}
de <- my_gather(mtcars, not.columns = quos(mpg, cyl, disp))
head(de, 3)
#   mpg cyl disp  k   v
#1 21.0   6  160 hp 110
#2 21.0   6  160 hp 110
#3 22.8   4  108 hp  93
```

Checking with the output without the function

```
de1 <- gather(mtcars, key = k, value = v, -mpg, -cyl, -disp)
identical(de, de1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: How does this differ from OP’s attempt? `UQS` = `!!!`; the `c` shouldn’t make a difference here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Yes, the `c` is the difference, But, I like to place it inside the braces

Comment: OK. Mind explaining why? It’s very much not obvious

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think the difference can be explained by comparing two commands: `'-'(1, 2, 3)` (gives error because function `-` needs one argument to change sign) and `'-'(c(1, 2, 3))` (gives expected result).
So `c` wraps column names to become one argument.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer "Answer the problem not the question" type of answer. You actually need a way to specify gathered columns having information about not used columns. Here is my way:

```
library(tidyverse)

negate_columns <- function(.tbl, not.columns) {
  not_columns <- colnames(select(.tbl, !!!not.columns))

  setdiff(colnames(.tbl), not_columns)
}

my_gather <- function(d, not.columns) {
  columns <- negate_columns(d, not.columns)

  tidyr::gather(d, key = k, value = v, !!!syms(columns))
}
```

This way it works as expected:

```
my_gather(mtcars, not.columns = quos(mpg, cyl, disp)) %>%
    head(3)
#>    mpg cyl disp  k   v
#> 1 21.0   6  160 hp 110
#> 2 21.0   6  160 hp 110
#> 3 22.8   4  108 hp  93
```